# How to override this function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I've got the following Javascript situation:

```
// First file - the one that I can't edit
(function(){
    "use strict";
    function test() {
        alert("a");
    }
    test();
})();
```

This is defined in a Javascript file which I cannot edit. How would I go about overriding the `test()` method?

Redefining the function doesn't work. The output is still "a".

```
// My file - trying to override the first file's test() function
(function(){
    function test() {
        alert("b");
    }
})();
```

Do you have any other suggestions?

In my mind the `test()` method must be defined *somewhere*, right? And if it is defined, I can override it.

Comment: `(function() {
  "use strict";

  function test() {
    console.log("a");
  }
  test();
})();
(function() {
  function test() {
    console.log("b");
  }
  test();
})();` is working... What is the issue ?

Comment: test is declared inside the outer function so is only in scope inside there.

Comment: The first file is already calling `test()`, so even if you override it somewhere else, it's already been called so it wouldn't matter,

Comment: @BrianGlaz that is understandable. But now, what if `test()` gets called later on, by some Javascript trigger?

Comment: `test` would be undefined since it's wrapped in a closure. You can try it in the dev console. Run the code you have in "first file" and then try to call `test` after it.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the function to a variable to create locally scoped functions that will behave the same within it's own function scope.

A scoped variable has priority over a global variable. So if you define a local variable in your own function you're overriding the other defined one. within the scope you're working in of course. On the outside of your scope the global object still persists.

You can't override a function in another scope. That is why a scoped function is scoped. It will keep a reference to it's local scoped variable. That's why the scopes are generally used, so you can encapsulate and protect your code to assure your code keeps working as intended.

unless it's a publicly exposed method, you can't override it.

```
(function(){
    var test = function() {
        alert("b");
    }
})();
```

```js
(function(){
    "use strict";
    function test() {
        console.log("a");
    }
    test();
})();
(function(){
    var test = function() {
        console.log("b");
    }
    test();
})();
```

Comment: He can't edit the file that test() is defined in, so I'm not sure if that'll work for him

Comment: Why `(function() {
  "use strict";

  function test() {
    console.log("a");
  }
  test();
})();
(function() {
  function test() {
    console.log("b");
  }
  test();
})();` will not work ?

Comment: You're working with scopes. It's aways better then to use var name = function(). that way the function will not be declared on the global window object/function registiry. In a scoped function +(function(){})() you will want to keep everything self contained.

Answer (score -1):

The text of the file can be edited if file is requested using XMLHttpRequest or fetch, then set edited response text to .textContent of script element, append script element to document.